# Custom LinkedBlockingQueue deadlock

Tags: java, deadlock, blockingqueue

I have been using custom blockingqueue inside `ThreadExecutorPool`, but some times task workers do not take task and dispacher thread does not put a new task into queue.

I wonder following custom blocking queue implementation causes deadlock. Is there any wrong with this code? 
Is is better to and `synchronized` block for `add()` and `take()` methods.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.ttech.utils.alarm.Alarm;
import com.ttech.utils.alarm.AlarmInterface;
import com.ttech.utils.counter.Counter;
import com.ttech.utils.counter.SNMPAgent;

public class WorkerQueue<E> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Integer lowThreshold;

    public Integer highThreshold;

    public Integer capacity;

    public String name;

    public String type;

    public Counter counter = null;

    public boolean writeAlarmLog;

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WorkerQueue.class);

    public static Alarm HighThresholdAlarm = null;
    public static Alarm CapacityAlarm = null;

    // Check the size here and clear capacity and high threshold alarms in case
    public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        E data = super.take();
        counter.setNewValue(super.size());
        if (super.size() == lowThreshold) {            
            if(!this.writeAlarmLog) {
                HighThresholdAlarm.clear(name);
                CapacityAlarm.clear(name);
            } else {
                HighThresholdAlarm.clearLog(name, "Queue High Threshold");
                CapacityAlarm.clearLog(name, "Queue Capacity Overload");
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public E poll() {
        E data = super.poll();
        counter.setNewValue(super.size());
        if (super.size() == lowThreshold) {
            if(!this.writeAlarmLog) {
                HighThresholdAlarm.clear(name);
                CapacityAlarm.clear(name);
            } else {
                HighThresholdAlarm.clearLog(name, "Queue High Threshold");
                CapacityAlarm.clearLog(name, "Queue Capacity Overload");
            }
        }
        return data;
    }


    public int drainTo(Collection<? super E> c, int maxElements){
       int size = super.drainTo(c,maxElements);       
       counter.setNewValue(super.size());       
       return size;
    }

    // During adding the data to queue check capacity and high threshold raise alarm in case
    public boolean add(E data) {
        Boolean rc = true;

        if (capacity > 0) {
            if (this.size() >= capacity) {
                logger.error("Queue " + name + " is over capacity");
                if(!this.writeAlarmLog)
                    CapacityAlarm.raise(name);
                else
                    CapacityAlarm.raiseLog(AlarmInterface.AS_CRITICAL, name, "Queue Capacity Overload");
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (!super.add(data)) {
            logger.error("Cannot add data to queue:" + name);
            rc = false;
        } else {
            counter.setNewValue(super.size());
        }

        if (highThreshold == super.size()) {


            if(!this.writeAlarmLog)
                HighThresholdAlarm.raise(name);
            else
                HighThresholdAlarm.raiseLog(AlarmInterface.AS_CRITICAL, name, "Queue High Threshold");
        }

        return rc;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i think you need `synchronized` methods, to make it thread safe, since you have class-scope members (variables and objects) AFAIK this is not thread safe.

Comment: My advice would be to never subclass any concurrent datastructure because it often leads to concurrency problems. Plus, making a queue responsible to raise alarms seems out of its expected scope (remember it's just a data structure). As teppic suggested, you should rather subclass `ThreadPoolExecutor` and use the `beforeExecute` and `afterExecute` to achieve your goal.

Comment: Aside note: all the `public` attributes are really frightening ! Have fun maintaining this class. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` does not `add` tasks to its work queue. It [offers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer-E-) them and if not accepted passes them to the configured [RejectedExecutionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html). By default this is the [abort policy handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy.html), which causes a `RejectedExecutionException` to be thrown.

The `add` method in your custom queue will never be called.

If you want to track changes in the number of in-flight tasks you have, I would suggest overriding the `beforeExecute` or `afterExecute` method of the executor itself. The number of active tasks can be obtained from `getActiveCount`.

Comment: Thanks, I have override offer() method as well. It works. Do I need to add syncronized block for these overrided methods.